# Private service and Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to migrate my Symfony 3.4 app to Symfony 4.1.

The tests are not working because the services are by default private (and it's a good news).

Following this post: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing, I am still facing the issue of private service :

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "my.service" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

In the following compiler pass, my private service was not found in the `$definitions` : `vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TestServiceContainerRealRefPass.php`

What should be the problem?

*UPDATED*

Here the definition :

```
    <service id="my.service"
             class="My\Bundle\GreatService">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    </service>
```

*UPDATED* (again)

Here the Unit test

```
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class MyServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected $myService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->myService = self::$container->get('my.service');
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the relevant parts of your service.yml to your question, so that we can see the information needed to answer your question. Also, you should add the function of the controller which fails, if it is a specific one.

Comment: are you trying to inject this service somewhere else ? If so you just have to declare it public : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html#marking-services-as-public-private (just set the public to true)

Comment: no, the service should stay private and we used this service by dependency injection. Not using the container. We used the container only on unit test. For that I followed the post : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing

Comment: A [PHPUnit Mock](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html) should be enough. If you really need the service, there is something wrong with your architecture.

Comment: It's actually an interesting problem.  [Some discussion here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8097).  A compiler pass for testing which sets everything to public might be the best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange that code above doesn't work. When I used symfony 4.0 I used such trick:

1.Add `services_test.yaml` in `config` folder with following content:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    public: true

  test.my.service: "@my.service"
```

2.Now you can get service from your container:

```
$this->myService = self::$container->get('test.my.service')
```

BTW do you inject this service somewhere, because unused services are removed by default (if they are not public or synthetic).

Comment: You found the reason : RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPass exists since previous version. And this compiler pass remove all unused private service. I am trying to run test on a library which will be used on several application. This library have many services but not injected. Previously, those services were public and in 4.* are private. When I try to run the unit test, those services were removed because not used. Thank you.

Comment: Juste a note to say that the correct yaml key is `_defaults`, not `_default`